How to calculate the time interval backwards in PHP
I have these PHP codes where I wanted to calculate the time difference between 2 given time.
// This is 2:00 am o'clock 
$time1 = 02:00;

// This is 9 pm o'clock
$time2 = 21:00;

I want to calculated backwards time difference between 2am - 9pm,  So the time difference should be 5hrs.
I tried the following but did not get the correct result:
$diff = date('H:i:s a', strtotime($time1)) - date('H:i:s a', strtotime($time2));

echo $diff;


You can't subtract formatted time strings. Subtract the numeric timestamps.

strtotime($time1) - strtotime($time2)

How do I do that

I get the results of 68400, which is not 5 hrs

Timestamps are seconds, you need to divide by 3600 to convert to hours.

You could also make use of the DateInterval class.

But 68400/3600 is 19 not 5hrs

Your time1 is BEFORE time2. So it's -19 hours.

Without explicit dates, the two timestamps will be assumed to occur on the same day. So you will need to either specify the day for each date or know for certain that $time2 always represents one previous day before $time1.

If the result is negative, add 24 to get the difference in the other order.

There is no explicit date, so are you saying this is not possible to calculate? or is there a way to get the correct interval of 5hrs?

Oh right, I think that's the trick, simply subtract 24hrs and 19! gotcha!

Are you trying to answer the question, "What's the minimum number of hours between any time1 and any time2?" Or, "What's the number of hours starting at time1 and going backwards until you hit the first time2?

The takeaway here should be that bare "time" values without an associated date are virtually meaningless.

<?php

$time1 = "21:00"; // 9:00 PM
$time2 = "02:00"; // 2:00 AM

// Convert the time strings to DateTime objects
$datetime1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i', $time1);
$datetime2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i', $time2);

// Calculate the time difference, accounting for crossing midnight
if ($datetime1 > $datetime2) {
    // Case where time2 is on the next day
    $datetime2->modify('+1 day');
}

$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);


echo "Backward Time interval: " . $interval->format('%H hours %I minutes') . "\n";

?>


Online Demo: https://onecompiler.com/php/42kbtdbzt
<?php
// Define the time variables
$time1 = "02:00";
$time2 = "21:00";

// Convert the time strings to DateTime objects
$datetime1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i', $time1);
$datetime2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i', $time2);

// Calculate the difference between the two times
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);

// Calculate the total minutes of the time difference
$totalMinutes = ($interval->h * 60) + $interval->i;

// Calculate the total minutes in a day
$minutesInDay = 24 * 60;

// Subtract the time difference from 24 hours
$remainingMinutes = $minutesInDay - $totalMinutes;

// Convert the remaining minutes back to hours and minutes
$remainingHours = floor($remainingMinutes / 60);
$remainingMinutes = $remainingMinutes % 60;


// Display the Time difference
echo "Time difference: " . $interval->format('%H hours %I minutes') ."\n";

// Display the remaining time
echo "Backwards time difference: " . $remainingHours . " hours " . $remainingMinutes . " minutes\n";

?>

